# EofException from Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, eof

We are migrating to Jetty 6.1 and we see a lot of following exceptions:

```
[2012-10-15 01:22:08,286: [btpool0-646] [] DEBUG,http.jetty.JettyServerManager] EOF
org.mortbay.jetty.EofException
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:302)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:205)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
        at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:450)
```

Although, till now I am not  not see any impact on the responses. Is there something wrong I have configured? These are DEBUG log statements, is it okay to ignore these?

Comment: gotta ask, why migrate _to_ a jetty release that is at minimum 2 years old...we are releasing jetty9 milestones already... http://www.eclipse.org/jetty

Comment: upgrading a third party package which contains jetty6 as dependency.

Comment: btw, as you are from Jetty team, any pointers for this debug stack trace should help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore this messages, I think they are produced if the remote browser closes the connection.
It is not an error.

Comment: but if the remote server closes connection, then I should see error at client, right? But i do not see any.

Comment: I see this debug messages also constantly, I haven't digged too much into it, since it's a debug. From my understanding, the jetty server logs this if the http connection is closed by the client browser, while jetty still thinks there is more to come.

Comment: Udo is correct, you see things like this when, for example, a user clicks 'go here' and then decides while the browser is trying to do it, they click stop, or navigate somewhere else instead.

Comment: but how to avoid this exception in logger file. its unnecessary generating and writing in my logger files. can you please suggest.

Comment: We get these messages when no browsers are running.